# Azure web role project not creating MbUnit test project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, azure, mbunit

We're creating an Azure cloud service project in VS 2010 with an ASP.Net MVC 2 web role.  When we create the MVC project we're asked if we want to create a test project.  Our choices are MbUnit3 (our preference) and MS Test.

When we select MbUnit, a test folder is created in the file system, but no project is created.  Choosing MS Test on the other hand does what you would expect and the test project appears in the solution explorer.

Does anyone know why the MbUnit test project isn't being created in this case?  If it's an Azure project hiccup vis-a-vis MbUnit, how can we create the project by hand and add it to the solution?

Thanks very much for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do it yourself, you can just create a new MVC project and later right-click on the roles node and add a web role using that project.  Be sure to mark the MVC assembly as "copy local" so it can run in the cloud (where MVC isn't installed in the GAC).

Comment: So create the MVC project outside of Azure (along with the MbUnit test project), then add it as a web role?  Sounds like a good idea, thanks.